# Intersection without cutting off whole polygon using QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, intersection

I am trying to intersect a larger map of MSOAs with a 50km ring to create a set of MSOAs within the ring. However, I would like to keep the MSOAs whole, even if not all of it lies within the 50km ring. I would like it to look like this:

[image]

Rather than this:

[image]

Does anyone know what I should be using to get something similar to the first example, rather than 'intersection' (which creates the 2nd example)?

Answer (score 4):

Use the `select by location` tool, first input being your polygons, second input being your circular buffer. Export the selected features to a new layer/file.

Comment: Or just "extract by location" to do it in a single step. Predicate "intersects".

Answer (score 3):

You can use *Extract by location* of the *Processing Toolbox*:

[image]

Result:

[image]

You can get to the processing toolbox by clicking on the wheel in the toolbar:

[image]

Answer (score -2):

If I understand you correctly, you can use the tool Union.

When he take two input layer and make them in to one.